# Scanner is not working properly

Tags: java, for-loop

So I am trying to learn Java. I wrote a simple program where I used a for loop and obtain user input.

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{   
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int number, numberOfValues, totalNumberOfRuns = 0;
    System.out.println("How many values?");
    numberOfValues = scan.nextInt();


    for (int w = 0; w < numberOfValues; w++)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter a number:" + "(" + numberOfValues-- + ")");
        number = scan.nextInt();    
        totalNumberOfRuns += number;
    }
        System.out.println("The total is " + totalNumberOfRuns);    
}       
}
```

The result is:

`How many values?
5
Enter a number:(5)
4
Enter a number:(4)
74
Enter a number:(3)
54
The total is 132`

What I want to do is to continue up to `Enter a number:(1)`

I know putting `numberOfValues` to the `System.out.println` inside the for loop is wrong. I am just experimenting to see what happens. But I ran out of ideas.

Any help will be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: How is the value `numberOfValues` getting decremented in the output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `numberOfValues - w` instead of `numberOfValues--`. This will fix the problem.

```
 System.out.println("Enter a number:" + "(" + (numberOfValues - w) + ")");
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix the loop as:

```
for (int w = 0; w < numberOfValues; w++)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter a number:" + "(" + (numberOfValues-w) + ")");
            number = scan.nextInt();
            totalNumberOfRuns += number;
        }
```

The problem with your code is following:

1. Your loop runs from `w=0` to `w=numberOfValues-1`.
2. In every loop iteration you are also decrementing value of numberOfValues by executing `numberOfValues--`.
3. So what actually happens for 5 is:

`w=0,  numberOfValues = 5
w=1,  numberOfValues = 4
w=2,  numberOfValues = 3`
And loop is over now.

List item

Answer (score 0):

If decrementing value of `numberOfValues` is not necessary then you can use `w` and can write `for loop` as follows -

```
 for (int w = numberOfValues; w>0; w--){
   System.out.println("Enter a number:" + "(" + w + ")");
   ...
}
```

This will work as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop condition is incorrect. Use `numberOfValues > 0` instead of `w < numberOfValues`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int number, numberOfValues, totalNumberOfRuns = 0;
        System.out.println("How many values?");
        numberOfValues = scan.nextInt();

        for (int w = 0; numberOfValues > 0; w++) {
            System.out.println("Enter a number:" + "(" + numberOfValues-- + ")");
            number = scan.nextInt();
            totalNumberOfRuns += number;
        }
        System.out.println("The total is " + totalNumberOfRuns);
    }
```